# Passing a javascript object as request parameter

Tags: javascript, jsp

Is there a way to pass a javascript object as a request parameter to a jsp?

I dont want to send mutliple comma separated strings.

My scenario is that I am parsin a json response and then I will have to pass the values in the json to another jsp.

Answer (score 1):

You could just re-build the JSON string (or even pass the original string along).

Comment: Rebuilding may be another complex operation as the JSON returned is from a solr index.

Comment: Let us say that my JSON response from SOLR returns 100 thousand records. I display the values in jsp and on clicking every record let us say that I want to pop up another window and show some selected attributes- This is the exact situation.